# How to add a control panel on a JTable row on MouseOver (hover)

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a **non editable** table, on which I'd like to display a **row contextual panel** (likely a `JPanel`). Somewhat like Gmail is doing: when moving the mouse over mail rows there's a simple tool bar showing up on that specific row.

[image: gmail]

Like in gmail the action of controls I'd like to display won't edit the values, instead they will use the value in the row to perform some offer work.

I have played with the following :

- `TableCellRenderer`, the display mostly works, but it has limitations:

  - the component is only used for rendering, so one cannot use it to simply add multiple buttons
  - it requires another column
  - for the hovering behavior (ie display on row only when the mouse is hovering the row) it requires collaboration with the table's `MouseListener`
- `TableCellEditor`, my table is not editable so the cell editor is neither called

  - it also requires a specific column
  - it also requires collaboration with the table's `MouseListener`
- `MouseMotionListener` can be used to display a popup for certain coordinates

  - the popup feels like it's the right component for this
  - there's quite some code to handle the popup lifecycle (closing it when the mouse move out of the row, don't re-open a popup if there is already one open)
- tool tips: as far as I am aware the swing tooltips do not allow to have control components like buttons, etc

I did related question and answer on stack overflow. But they all require to add a column to display and use these swing components.

Comment: *don't re-open a popup if there is already one open* I would use a `JPopupMenu`. You would track the current row. When it changes you hide the popup and redisplay it.

Comment: @camickr Thanks for the suggestion. This led me to `JLayeredPane`, I still have to issues about focus, display and layout with that approach though.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you have posted no code, this question is a bit broad.

Nevertheless, the way to do it would be to stick a JPanel in a JPopupMenu. You need to create a listener on your GUI to know when and where the JPopupMenu should appear

--- Edit ---

I think you have to add JMenus to a JPopupMenu, and what I suggested about adding a JPanel won't work cleanly. You can either use JPopupMenu, or use a JWindow and put your JPanel in that.

Comment: Hi @ControlAltDel, yes I don't think the code is necessary, as I'm trying to get the best angle to tackle this UX issue. I have started to work  with a `JLayeredPane` instead of creating a JWindow / JPopupMenu while I struggle with some layout / painting issue at the moment I believe the approach is better.